# Rewrite rule doesn't work when I directly type the URL in the browser

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I have this directory structure

```
/gallery
/home
    index.php
    (other files here).php
/products
/(other folders here)
index.php
```

In the root `index.php` there is a simple redirect:

```
<?php header('location: /home/');
```

Indeed, `home/index.php` is where the site (I mean: HTML, CSS, JS, etc.) starts

Now, since it's a dynamic site, I need some rewrite rules. Here they are, with my comments to help you understand:

```
# Add a trailing slash to folders that don't have one
# Wehen user types 'mysite.dev/folder' it is converted to 'mysite.dev/folder/'
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.)
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]

# Exclude these folders from rewrite process
# Am I right here? Is this rule right?
RewriteRule ^(admin|ajax|assets|blocks|cache|classes|Connections|cron|editor|inc|intranet|lang|loops|pub)($|/) - [L]

# Remember: the root 'index.php' redirects to '/home' folder: then
# we append the Italian language so that Italian site version is shown as default
RewriteRule ^(/home/)?$ /home/index.php?nLang=it [NC,L]

# Start rewriting rules
RewriteRule ^sfogliabile/([\d]+).htm$                   /flip/browser.php?iCat=$1                              [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^depliant/([\d]+).htm$                      /flip/flyer.php?iSpecial=$1                            [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/risultati.htm$                    /home/risultati.php?nLang=$1                           [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/cookie.htm$                       /home/cookie.php?nLang=$1                              [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/nojs.htm$                         /home/nojs.php?nLang=$1                                [NC,L]
#RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/professional/$                   /home/pro.php?nLang=$1                                 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/3/([\w-]+)/$                      /products/index.php?nLang=$1&iModule=3                 [NC,L]       # it/3/prodotti/, en/3/products/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/3/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)/([\w-]+).htm$  /products/details.php?nLang=$1&iData=$3&iModule=3      [NC,L]       # it/3/prodotti/1/prodotto-x.htm, en/3/products/1/product-x.htm
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/4/([\w-]+)/$                      /foreground/index.php?nLang=$1&iModule=4               [NC,L]       # it/4/primo-piano/, en/4/foreground/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/4/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)/([\w-]+).htm$  /foreground/details.php?nLang=$1&iData=$3&iModule=4    [NC,L]       # it/4/primo-piano/1/articolo-x.htm, en/4/foreground/1/article-x.htm
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/5/([\w-]+)/$                      /specials/index.php?nLang=$1&iModule=5                 [NC,L]       # it/5/speciali/, en/5/specials/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/5/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)/([\w-]+).htm$  /specials/details.php?nLang=$1&iData=$3&iModule=5      [NC,L]       # it/5/speciali/1/articolo-x.htm, en/5/specials/1/article-x.htm
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/6/([\w-]+)/$                      /gallery/index.php?nLang=$1&iModule=6                  [NC,L]       # it/6/gallerie/, en/6/galleries/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/6/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)/([\w-]+).htm$  /gallery/details.php?nLang=$1&iData=$3&iModule=6       [NC,L]       # it/6/gallerie/1/galleria-x.htm, en/6/galleries/1/gallery-x.htm
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([\w-]+)/([\d]+)/([\w-]+).htm$    /home/page.php?nLang=$1&iData=$3                       [NC,L,QSA]   # it/azienda/1/pagina-x.htm, en/company/1/page-x.htm

# solution from http://stackoverflow.com/a/39931184/160044
# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}     !-f
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/$             home/index.php?nLang=$1     [L,QSA,NC]
```

This is fine, seems that everything works as expected, but with an only caveat.
When I type `mysite.dev` + [Enter] in the browser I am redirected to `mysite.dev/home/index.php?nLang=it`, exposing things I don't want to and undermining rewrite process: why does it happens? Where am I wrong?

When I delete the `/home/index.php?nLang=it` part and press [Enter], everything is fine: there is ony the `mysite.dev` part, that is what I'd expect (or at least `mysite.dev/it/` would be fine too)

Want to see the Apache errors.log? Here it is (don't know why it considers also folders that shouldn't be considered, as `assets` or `pub`), just replace `mysite.dev` with `ljpharma.dev`:

```
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '(.*)' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^(admin|ajax|assets|blocks|cache|classes|Connections|cron|editor|inc|intranet|lang|loops|pub|webassist)($|/)' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^(/home/)?$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^sfogliabile/([\\d]+).htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^depliant/([\\d]+).htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.251836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/risultati.htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/cookie.htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/nojs.htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/3/([\\w-]+)/$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/3/([\\w-]+)/([\\d]+)/([\\w-]+).htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/4/([\\w-]+)/$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/4/([\\w-]+)/([\\d]+)/([\\w-]+).htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/5/([\\w-]+)/$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/5/([\\w-]+)/([\\d]+)/([\\w-]+).htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/6/([\\w-]+)/$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/6/([\\w-]+)/([\\d]+)/([\\w-]+).htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/([\\w-]+)/([\\d]+)/([\\w-]+).htm$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^([a-z]+)/$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '^(.*)$' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php -> home/index.php
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] applying pattern '(^|/)\\.' to uri 'home/index.php'
[Sat Jul 08 16:05:15.252836 2017] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 28420:tid 1232] mod_rewrite.c(477): [client 127.0.0.1:51317] 127.0.0.1 - - [ljpharma.dev/sid#2ee51d8][rid#4ec1ee0/initial] [perdir D:/Web/ljpharma/] pass through D:/Web/ljpharma/home/index.php
```

Any help, please? Thanks

EDIT: Uh-Oh... I noticed that if I put the following rule BEFORE all the other (and NOT AFTER as it's now) everything seems to work... could this be the cause? If yes, am I forced to put this BEFORE everything else or is there a workaround?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(/home/)?$` The `?` makes this whole term optional and `^$` (meaning nothing other than the root domain) will match the url your are typing in.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, @colburton: then I removed the root `index.php` file, but the problem remains

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always place redirects before internal rewrites, even though it is unclear to me why you experience a domain change based on these rules.

When rewriting an url, Apache goes through the .htaccess file repeatedly until the url does no longer change. Why is this important? Well, take the following example:

```
#The internal rewrite
RewriteRule ^foo$ /bar [L]

#The external redirect
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

When we enter the url `http://localhost/foo`, Apache will go through the rules and will match the first one. It will now go through the rules **again** with the url `http://localhost/bar` and match the second rule and will then redirect to `https://localhost/bar`. Apache will not evaluate the rules again after encountering the `R` flag and after the current run through the rules is stopped, e.g. by encountering the `L` flag or reaching the end of the .htaccess file.

If you put the redirects first, you will match `http://localhost/foo` against the redirect-rule, which will make the browser request `https://localhost/bar`. Now Apache will match that url in the new request, which will no longer match any redirects, but will match the internal rewrite, and will internally try to serve resource `bar`.

---

On a side-note: In .htaccess files, the matched resource is guaranteed to not start with a `/` as a .htaccess file is in a directory, and this directory is stripped from the matched url and reapplied after rewriting. As such, the `RewriteRule ^(/home/)?$ ...` rule is a bit silly, as the part within the parentheses is guaranteed to be never matched. Change it to `RewriteRule ^(home/?)?$ ...` if you want it to match a path starting with `home` too.